# how to compare in two $http.get and get the required property

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have two function both function has $http.get method.first method has response.response.data[6] and second function as response.response.data[76].the first function has 6 object which also available in second function. to compare and get the require property

```
 angular.module('ob3App.lead')
        .controller('LeadProductCtrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {

        $scope.namegetfunction = function() {

        $scope.products=[];
        $scope.idValue=[];    
            $http.get("http://5.9.42.45:8080/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/Product?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k")
            .success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.names = response.response.data;
            console.log($scope.names.length);

            $scope.names.forEach(function(item) {
              console.log(item.name);
             $scope.products.push(item.name);
            })

            console.log($scope.products);

$scope.names.forEach(function(ids){
            console.log(ids.id);
            $scope.idValue.push(ids.id);
        })

        console.log($scope.idValue);

            })
            .error(function(response){
                alert('error in name');
            });
        };
        $scope.namegetfunction();

        $scope.imageGetFunction = function() {
            $scope.imageArray=[];

            $http.get("http://5.9.42.45:8080/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/ADImage?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k")
            .success(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.image = response.response.data;
                console.log($scope.names.length);

                $scope.image.forEach(function(item) {
                    console.log(item.bindaryData);
                    $scope.imageArray.push(item.bindaryData);
                })
                console.log($scope.imageArray);

            })
            .error(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                alert('error in image');
            });
        };
        $scope.imageGetFunction();

     }]);
```

both function has a unique one which is ID property in the array. with the help of first function 'ID' property  i need to invoke second property binary data property and get display in ionic

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive flat">
        <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="back()"><i class="ion-arrow-left-c"> </i></button>
        <h1 class="title">Products</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>

        <ul class="list">

            <li class="item" ng-repeat="i in products" ui-sref="leadProduct" >
                {{i}}
                <br>
                <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/100x100">

            </li>
        </ul>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

second function console.log(response) out put

```
response: Object
data: Array[73]
0: Object
1: Object
$ref: "ADImage/F323D8FF424E4A138D55C710768E9455"
_entityName: "ADImage"
_identifier: "Image"
active: true
bindaryData: "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"
client: "DA7A27EAF5FB4BFBBAB88EADAA3EE0A0"
client$_identifier: "Aluminium Fortune Aluminium"
createdBy: "62B215CFF490454DBE1939879A14E6CA"
createdBy$_identifier: "saiy5k - "
creationDate: "2015-10-22T12:17:28+02:00"
height: 320
id: "F323D8FF424E4A138D55C710768E9455"
imageURL: null
mimetype: "image/png"
name: "Image"
organization: "A9D87DB96C24465489ECF3C3AAF563B1"
organization$_identifier: "Fortune Aluminium"
recordTime: 1450938045552
updated: "2015-10-22T12:17:28+02:00"
updatedBy: "62B215CFF490454DBE1939879A14E6CA"
updatedBy$_identifier: "saiy5k - "
width: 320
__proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
```

first function console.log(response) output

```
response: Object
data: Array[6]
0: Object
$ref: "Product/CEE73A0F92C04AF3853B12FF141CD6BB"
_entityName: "Product"
_identifier: "Wheat"
active: true
attributeSet: null
attributeSetValue: null
bOMVerified: false
billOfMaterials: false
bookUsingPurchaseOrderPrice: false
brand: null
businessPartner: null
calculated: false
capacity: null
characteristicDescription: null
classification: null
client: "DA7A27EAF5FB4BFBBAB88EADAA3EE0A0"
client$_identifier: "Aluminium Fortune Aluminium"
comments: null
costType: null
createVariants: false
createdBy: "62B215CFF490454DBE1939879A14E6CA"
createdBy$_identifier: "saiy5k - "
creationDate: "2015-08-27T10:09:45+02:00"
defaultPeriod: null
defaultPeriodExpense: null
deferredRevenue: false
description: null
descriptionURL: null
discontinued: false
discontinuedBy: null
downloadURL: null
enforceAttribute: false
expenseType: null
expplantype: null
freightCategory: null
genericProduct: null
guaranteedDays: null
helpComment: null
id: "CEE73A0F92C04AF3853B12FF141CD6BB"
image: null
imageURL: null
isGeneric: false
isdeferredexpense: false
isquantityvariable: false
manageVariants: false
maxQuantity: null
minQuantity: null
minimumLeadTime: null
minimumStock: null
name: "Wheat"
name2: null
opcrmDescription: null
opcrmUpc2: null
opcrmUpc3: null
opcrmUrl: null
organization: "A9D87DB96C24465489ECF3C3AAF563B1"
organization$_identifier: "Fortune Aluminium"
periodNumber: null
periodnumberExp: null
planner: null
planningMethod: null
printDetailsOnInvoice: false
printDetailsOnPickList: false
printPrice: true
processNow: false
processPlan: null
productCategory: "CC6FD7550F0047A8BD2CF378A4B4591A"
productCategory$_identifier: "Groceries"
productType: "I"
production: false
purchase: true
quantityType: false
recordTime: 1450938045518
resource: null
revenuePlanType: null
sKU: null
safetyStock: null
sale: true
salesRepresentative: "62B215CFF490454DBE1939879A14E6CA"
salesRepresentative$_identifier: "saiy5k"
searchKey: "WHE"
shelfDepth: null
shelfHeight: null
shelfWidth: null
standardCost: null
standardQuantity: null
stocked: true
storageBin: "AF1099E5F71D414EA52F1EC9652A6C79"
storageBin$_identifier: "Default Bin"
summaryLevel: false
taxCategory: "2BC263B831934106B12B50C6B7313E29"
taxCategory$_identifier: "Income Tax"
uOM: "72BA247D31F745F3AF11F74A5E2CCBEF"
uOM$_identifier: "Kilogram"
uOMForWeight: null
uPCEAN: null
unitsPerPallet: null
updateInvariants: false
updated: "2015-08-27T10:09:45+02:00"
updatedBy: "62B215CFF490454DBE1939879A14E6CA"
updatedBy$_identifier: "saiy5k - "
useAttributeSetValueAs: null
versionNo: null
volume: 0
weight: 0
```

Comment: You mean the second function should return images by matching ID's from both function?? so in this case are you expecting 6 images from second function. Is that correct ??

Comment: yes correct by matching the id i should invoke 'binary data' property from the second function

Comment: in  $scope.idValue=[]; i got 6 'id' with the help of that i should compare to the second function 'id' properties and invoke the 'binary data' property

Comment: Whether `` $scope.idValue`` is available with 6 ids in second function ?? Can you also show some sample image data that you are getting from 2nd function ??

Comment: the image data will be in base 64 formate string and it is strode in 'binary data' property but in $scope.idValue=[]; there is no 'binary data' property.please use my url in restclient or in postman to get the data so that you can get some id

Comment: in  $scope.imageArray=[]; i should have the the binary data property value in it by using the $scope.idValue=[]; id

Comment: Due to proxy restriction here cant open the URL. If you are getting ids in 2nd function , then you can loop through them, then use ``filterFilter`` to filter out image data and push it to ``imageArray``. If you can show  sample data then it helps to solve the issue.

Comment: yes the same id in the $scope.idValue=[] is also available in second function i need to use the same id to filter in second function and then i should get binary data property. the value in binary data is in base64 formate if you just search in google you can see how it will be look like

Comment: $scope.imageArray.push(item.bindaryData); is used to get the value but i am getting all the 76 binary data string but i need only 6 which is in first function

Comment: I know how binary data looks like , no need to search. But wanted know how your image data response looks like. I will post sample code considering that your image data response has ids.

Comment: sorry sammer i am not able to get what your asking from me is it possible to show some samples

Comment: No problem, i have posted some sample code , try it out n let me know the status.  you misspelled my name. Its Sameer not Sammer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject `filterFilter` into controller function and try with below function.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('LeadProductCtrl',['$scope','$http','filterFilter', function($scope,$http, filterFilter) {
    $scope.products=[];
    $scope.idValue=[];
    $scope.namegetfunction = function() {
        $scope.names = {};
        $http.get("http://5.9.42.45:8080/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/Product?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k")
            .success(function(response) {
                //console.log(response);
                $scope.names = response.response.data;
                $scope.names.forEach(function(ids){

                    $scope.idValue.push(ids.id);
                });
                $scope.imageGetFunction();
            })
            .error(function(response){
                alert('error in name');
            });


    };

    $scope.namegetfunction();

    $scope.imageGetFunction = function() {
        console.log( $scope.idValue);
        $scope.imageArray=[];
        $http.get("http://5.9.42.45:8080/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/ADImage?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k")
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            angular.forEach($scope.idValue, function(val, key) {
                if(filterFilter(response.response.data, {id : val})) {
                    console.log(val);
                    $scope.imageArray.push(response.response.data.bindaryData);
                }
            });
            console.log($scope.imageArray);

        })
        .error(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            alert('error in image');
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: i am geting an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { like this

Comment: if(filterFilter(response.response.data, {id : val}) { in this line it is showning error

Comment: like filterFilter is not defined

Comment: Updated my answer, i had missed closing ``)`` for ``if`` condition.

Comment: ReferenceError: filterFilter is not defined

Comment: Have you injected ``filterFilter`` into you controller ?

Comment: Inject it like ``controller('LeadProductCtrl',['$scope','$http', 'filterFilter', function($scope,$http, filterFilter)``

Comment: now only i did thanks but my reqirement is to have only the 6 binaryData property value in array i am getting all the 76 binaryData property value in the array just like before in my code also gives me the same out put

Comment: You need make series of checks. First check if you are getting ids in loop and then ``response.response.data`` has ``id`` in it or not.  It would be helpfull if you share the data that are getting for ``$scope.idValue`` and ``response``

Comment: ya sure but i dont know how to share it with you can you help me how to show the data or shall i copy and past the console.log(response)

Comment: Share the console.log out put.

Comment: please check my updated question have posted the console.log output for second function

Comment: ``id: "F323D8FF424E4A138D55C710768E9455"`` is this the id to be matched?? and also share the ``console.log(response);`` out put of the 1st function..

Comment: no i am showing the expample formate in the object check my updated first function console.log.(response)

Comment: The 2nd function starts executing and it its not waiting for 1st function to complete. So when i tried your code, the ``$scope.idValue`` is undefined in second function

Comment: but in my console.log($scope.idValue) i got 6 id values

Comment: I have updated my answer after work around. Kept only necessary code with respect the question.  I have called 2nd function inside success part of 1st function and getting exactly 6 values in 2nd function.  Try it n hope will resolve your issue.

Comment: console.log(val); we got the same id available in  $scope.idValue=[]; and in the  console.log($scope.imageArray); i am getting 6 undefined value not the base64 string

Comment: [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

Comment: sorry to disturb you sameer i tried a lot but i still not able to get base64 string in my array please help me

Comment: Was struck with some other work. Ok lets try some hard coding.  Copy ``id`` from 2nd function response and pass it to filterFilter function like ``var test = filterFilter(response.response.data, {id : 'pass id here'}`` and console.log (test) and see if you are getting any result. dont worry binay now and you can comment that loop also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452335/how-to-access-the-property-from-particular-object-in-angularjs

Comment: i get  6 empty array one by one nothing inside it

Comment: sorry sameer yesterday we where look at the worng id here is the improved question which will give the base64 string in the array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460454/how-to-access-the-property-of-an-object-using-the-unique-property-value