# Comparing to array index value

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The length of the imagevalue array is 6.

```
 $scope.imageValue=[];
```

The length of imageArray is 73.

```
$scope.imageArray=[];
```

I use for and if loop to check if any of the index in `imagevalue` array is equal to any of the index in `imageArray` .

```
for(var i = 0;i <= $scope.names.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<=$scope.imageID.length;j++){
        if($scope.imageValue[i] == $scope.imageArray[j]) {
            $scope.testArray.push($scope.imageID[j].bindaryData);
            console.log($scope.testArray);
            return true;
        }
        else if($scope.imageValue[i] !== $scope.imageArray[j]){
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

If so then I have to push the `bindaydata` value in the empty array `testArray`

```
$scope.testArray=[];
```

My over all code looks like

```
angular.module('ob3App.lead')
    .controller('LeadProductCtrl',['$scope','$http','filterFilter', function($scope,$http,filterFilter) {

    $scope.namegetfunction = function() {
      $scope.imageValue=[];
    $http.get("http://5.9.42.45:8080/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/Product?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k")
        .success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.names = response.response.data;
        console.log($scope.names.length);
        $scope.names.forEach(function(ids){
            console.log(ids.id);
            $scope.imageValue.push(ids.image);
        })
        $scope.imageGetFunction();
        console.log($scope.imageValue);
        })
        .error(function(response){
            alert('error in name');
        });
    };
    $scope.namegetfunction();

    $scope.imageGetFunction = function() {
        $scope.imageArray=[];
        $scope.testArray=[];

        $http.get("http://5.9.42.45:8080/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/ADImage?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k")
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.imageID = response.response.data;
            console.log($scope.imageID.length);

            $scope.imageID.forEach(function(item) {
                $scope.imageArray.push(item.id);
            })

            console.log($scope.imageArray);

            for(var i = 0;i <= $scope.names.length;i++) {
                for(var j=0;j<=$scope.imageID.length;j++){
                    if($scope.imageValue[i] == $scope.imageArray[j]) {
                        $scope.testArray.push($scope.imageID[j].bindaryData);
                        console.log($scope.testArray);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if($scope.imageValue[i] !== $scope.imageArray[j]){
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
              console.log($scope.testArray);

        })
        .error(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            alert('error in image');
        });
    };

 }]);
```

Comment: $scope.imageId[j].bindaryData is misspelled

Comment: no property name is actualy bindaryData no mistake and i have a doubut  $scope.imageID[j] is this specification is correct or not

Comment: s u r right thanks and one of my previews question have the sample output here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447427/how-to-compare-in-two-http-get-and-get-the-required-property

Comment: console.log(response) of first function and console.log(response) of second function is given

Comment: actualy i and j variable refer to the index value of an array and $scope.imageValue=[]; as the 'image' property value and its length is 6 and $scope.imageArray=[]; as the 'id' property value and its length is 73 if both index matches then push bindaryData property in the testArray if not equal then push null value to array

Comment: correct if the value matches then i have to push the bindaryData property which is available in the imageGetFuntion URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out it works fine

```
for(var indexOfProduct = 0;indexOfProduct< $scope.productImage.length;indexOfProduct++){
            console.log(indexOfProduct);
            console.log($scope.productImage.length);
            if($scope.productImage[indexOfProduct].image == null) {
                    console.log($scope.productImage[indexOfProduct].image);
                    $scope.base64Array.push(null);
                    console.log($scope.base64Array);

                }
                else if($scope.productImage[indexOfProduct].image !== null) {
                    for(var indexOfAdImage =0;indexOfAdImage<=$scope.imageID.length;indexOfAdImage++){
                    console.log(indexOfAdImage);
                        if($scope.productImage[indexOfProduct].image == $scope.imageID[indexOfAdImage].id) {
                            console.log($scope.imageID[indexOfAdImage].bindaryData);
                            $scope.base64Array.push($scope.imageID[indexOfAdImage].bindaryData);
                            console.log($scope.base64Array);
                            break;
                        }
                    }    
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.imageId[j].bindaryData
```

should be

```
$scope.imageID[j].bindaryData
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kGCln96vqetu5CqnloYK?p=preview

Comment: imageURL what it does

Comment: i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Comment: actually in your answer $scope.imageArray[j].imageURL i think it is no needed because in $scope.imageArray[j] itself contains the data which we have to compare with $scope.Value[i] and in the second if condition i think there is some mistake

Comment: and one more thing for comparison we use id property from imageGetFunction URL and image property from namegetfunction URL

Comment: yes but actually all the possible id property and image property is available in the $scope.imageArray and $scope.imageValue now we just need to compore the index of the of both array i think no nee to get the $scope.imageValue[i].id like that

Comment: @MohanGopi But you are doing the comparison so you can access the $scope.imageID[j].bindaryData  So you kind of do need to itterate and compare the objects. Other wise you need to reformat your question more clearly.

Comment: sorry but actually my requirement needs to be do the comparison between the index like imagevalue[0]==imageArray[0]; imagevalue[0]==imageArray[1];imagevalue[0]==imageArray[3];

Comment: @MohanGopi Try that then

Comment: @MohanGopi There is no guarantee that the ids will be the correct matches. It makes more sense to compare the response objects like I wrote before. Please format your question with requirements. The original need was: i am not able to view the console.log($scope.testArray); in browser  ... That was a syntax error. That resolved you original question.

Comment: if ($scope.imageID[k].id == $scope.imageArray[j].id ) in this line imageID and imageArray both have the same id no need to check this but imagevalue and imageArray r different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98962/discussion-between-kcbeard-and-mohan-gopi).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98963/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-kcbeard).

Comment: i dont have 20 reputation to continue in chat

Comment: i added a plunker, you do not have an name.image that is equal to an image.id

Comment: So which $scope.imageID[j].bindaryData do you want? the name.image doesn't match the image.id.

Comment: check your answer can we do like that

Comment: @MohanGopi Please view the plunker using the console editor. Please accept my answer, it did complete your questions.